# How to remove a Symfony service? (Sonata Classification)

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I'm using SonataAdminBundle with MediaBundle that has a dependency on ClassificationBundle. By default, ClassificationBundle adds in backend admin management for categories, tags, collections and contexts, but since my application doesn't use them I want to remove them from the menu and admin panel.

I've never removed a service before, so I don't know how to do it.

There has to be a way to remove these services from `SonataClassificationBundle/Resources/config/admin.xml`, obviously without modifying the file itself because it is a vendor file.

```
 <services>
        <service id="sonata.classification.admin.category" class="%sonata.classification.admin.category.class%">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_classification" label="label_categories"  label_catalogue="%sonata.classification.admin.category.translation_domain%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore" />
            <argument />
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.category.entity%</argument>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.category.controller%</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.classification.manager.context" />

            <call method="setTranslationDomain">
                <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.category.translation_domain%</argument>
            </call>

            <call method="setTemplates">
                <argument type="collection">
                    <argument key="list">SonataClassificationBundle:CategoryAdmin:list.html.twig</argument>
                </argument>
            </call>
        </service>

        <service id="sonata.classification.admin.tag" class="%sonata.classification.admin.tag.class%">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_classification" label="label_tags"  label_catalogue="%sonata.classification.admin.tag.translation_domain%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore" />
            <argument />
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.tag.entity%</argument>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.tag.controller%</argument>

            <call method="setTranslationDomain">
                <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.tag.translation_domain%</argument>
            </call>
        </service>

        <service id="sonata.classification.admin.collection" class="%sonata.classification.admin.collection.class%">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_classification" label="label_collections"  label_catalogue="%sonata.classification.admin.collection.translation_domain%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore" />
            <argument />
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.collection.entity%</argument>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.collection.controller%</argument>

            <call method="setTranslationDomain">
                <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.collection.translation_domain%</argument>
            </call>
        </service>

        <service id="sonata.classification.admin.context" class="%sonata.classification.admin.context.class%">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_classification" label="label_contexts"  label_catalogue="%sonata.classification.admin.context.translation_domain%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore" />
            <argument />
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.context.entity%</argument>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.context.controller%</argument>

            <call method="setTranslationDomain">
                <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.context.translation_domain%</argument>
            </call>
        </service>
    </services>
```

Or maybe is there a way to remove them from the Sonata admin pool? Since they are tagged with `sonata.admin`?

**EDIT**

Using Sonata Easy Extends I've extended the bundle and added a Compiler Pass:

```
class ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'SonataClassificationBundle';
    }

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new CustomCompilerPass());
    }

}
```

The compiler pass looks like this

```
class CustomCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->removeDefinition('sonata.classification.admin.category');
    }
}
```

But I'm getting

```
  You have requested a non-existent service "sonata.classification.admin.cate  
  gory" in . (which is being imported from "E:\svn\parkresort\app/config\rout  
  ing/sonata.yml").
```

That file is importing the routing for the whole sonata bundle

```
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

#sonata media
media:
    resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/media.xml'
    prefix: /media
```

I guess the service is being used by sonata admin even after being removed from the container. How can I change that?

**EDIT2**

I did it! I had to put the Compiler Pass in Sonata Admin Extension(with its namespace) and not in  Sonata Media. Also extending the Admin bundle, obviously. Worked just fine afterwards.

What I don't really understand is why it works when the original bundle is loaded after my extended bundle:

```
//AppKernel.php
new ApplicationSonataAdminBundle(),//extended
new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
```

That is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're talking about a bundle which is a dependency of your application, you have no control over what services it defines and registers into your application.

I believe it's possible to remove them using [ContainerBuilder::removeDefinition()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php#L372). It will work for services defined in other bundles as well, therefore it will work on the Sonata bundle.

You can see an example in [Symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) on exactly where to put this code and how to gain access to the `ContainerBuilder` object.

However, I advise you to not do this. Even though you won't use some services, they won't bother you and, given how Symfony handles services, they won't cause any performance problems in production, I promise.

Comment: They don't bother me, but they bother my client. He might 'play' in there and break something, or they might just want those unnecessary categories removed. That is the problem. Also, why don't you advise this? What problems can there be? The admin services aren't used anywhere else.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc It's like having a car. And you completely remove the back seat. You'll say to yourself that it's not a problem, you won't have any passengers anyway. And it won't be a problem.... until it is. Because at some point someone will expect those services to be there and try to use them.... and when they fail, they'll lose days trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: It's ok to remove the back seat if the car is meant to not have passengers. If that's what the buyer asks. And in this specific case nobody will miss those services for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a compiler pass to remove the definition. 
In order to be able to do that you have to make sure your bundle is declared after the Sonata one. If you can't control that, then [extend](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) the Sonata bundle and define the compiler pass in it.

Comment: That is strange. If I add it after, I get the error in the first edit of my question with 'You have requested a non-existent service '. But if I let it first and then add the original Sonata in AppKernel.php it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Half a year later, I found a much cleaner way that keeps the services in the container(because they are needed somewhere), but doesn't show them on the admin panel.

```
   $definitionsNames = array('sonata.media.admin.media', 'sonata.media.admin.gallery_has_media', 'sonata.media.admin.gallery',
        'sonata.classification.admin.category','sonata.classification.admin.tag','sonata.classification.admin.context','sonata.classification.admin.collection');

    foreach ($definitionsNames as $definitionName) {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition($definitionName);

        $tags = $definition->getTags();

        $tags['sonata.admin'][0]['show_in_dashboard'] = false;
        $definition->setTags($tags);

    }
```

Unfortunately, the admin routes are still available. Not an issue for my side, but I believe there are ways to remove them.
The thing is the media_widget contains a link to the admin media edit route, so that needs to be overwritten to not show it anymore. Then the Media, Gallery and GHM admins need to be overridden, and override the configureroutes() function and remove all routes. Then I believe you can't access anything through the admin, but the application can still use the admin services, if they are needed anywhere.

This way, I still follow Radu's advice of not removing services from the container.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I encounter the same problem and achieved to remove the desired services using a Compiler pass (in Symfony 4 and above).

Create a compiler pass which remove your services:

```php
namespace App\DependencyInjection\CompilerPass;

use MyService;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class RemoveUnusedServices implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->removeDefinition(MyService::class);
    }
}
```

and register this service into the `App` class:

```php
namespace App;

use App\DependencyInjection\CompilerPass\RemoveUnusedServices;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PassConfig;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class App extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new RemoveUnusedServices(), PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION, -2000);
        // (add the desired priority, if needed)
    }
}
```

Sometimes, the service you want to remove is also in used in the definition of another service (for instance, [using method calls](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html)).

If this is the case, you will have to alter also the definition of the affected services (using [`Definition`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.php)).

```php
$affected = $container->getDefinition(MyDependentService::class);
// then, you have to alter the configuration, using Definition
// i.e.:
//$affected->replaceArgument(0, new Definition(AnotherService::class));
```

**Note**: another way to change the behaviour of an app is [to decorates the services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) you would like to change to give the desired behaviour. This may be easier.